# Can a message queue be shared across PHP scripts?

Tags: php, scripting, message-queue

How do I create message queue in PHP, such that it can be modified and read by 2 different scripts running at the same time? Or is it better to use a [database for this](http://www.freeopenbook.com/php-hacks/phphks-CHP-5-SECT-18.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, that's definitely a database project. Are you talking about simple messages that you're posting to the server from forms, error messages, or emails?

If you're doing something like personal messaging or something similar where the messages will be accessed through the browser, use a database.

If it's for storing error messages, it's best to use something like php's log files... Write to the files with your error function each time an error occurs.

If you're queuing emails, it's best to use your server's mail system for queuing them.